# Javascript directory issue

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so please be patient.  I've created a folder (kiddieland) and pointed a URL to it.  I need javascript to tell an iframe it's source based on the name of the page. Below is what I came up with.  For some reason, the source adds the root folder to the string.  The request url should be /pages/galleria/KDR7778.html.

## Error Message

The requested URL /kiddieland/pages/galleria/KDR7778.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

## Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageName = location.pathname.substring(1);
    var pageName2 = pageName.substring(6);
    var pageName3 = pageName2.substring(0,7);
    var showPageName = pageName3.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("showName").src = "/pages/galleria/" + showPageName + ".html";
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a folder outside of your root directory? In that case you should either remodel your site or point to the page explicitly with the full address.

Comment: try the full path or check if the path is correctly referenced from the directory from which the file is executed....this seems a bit different path notation starting with / instead use ./ ,not really sure what is your server linux or windows

Comment: It is linux server.  The root domain is dj-by-request.com and the url uncadaveskiddieland.com is pointing to a folder called kiddieland under the dj-by-request domain.  Anyone browsing uncadaveskiddieland.com will never see the root domain.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  I had to use full path.